# Typescript - validating the values of one parameter based off of another

Tags: typescript

I'm attempting to create a react component that renders a table of inputs based on a configuration object, which defines the field property names and their input types, and initial rows of data.

Here is an example of intended usage:

```
const render = <C extends Config>(config: C, initialData: Row<C>[]) => {
  return initialData
}

const config = {
  properties: [
    {
      input: InputType.Text,
      label: 'Crop',
      name: 'crop',
    },
    {
      input: InputType.Number,
      label: 'Yield(t)',
      name: 'yield_t',
    },
  ],
}

const initialData = [
  { crop: 'corn', yield_t: 2 },
  { crop: 'barley', yield_t: 2 },
  { crop: 2, yield_t: 'ten' }, // ❌ bad input
]

render(config, initialData)
```

I am trying to get instances like the above, with bad input, to make Typescript complain.

Here's what I have so far ([also in a TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKhFgCgAIWh1AkgBQFxVhuBBAdtAQwBciBTAWwAcjoiB7aAYwCdTjTaBPS0gZxYCW1ALQAbUgDdSorj2gSCogQBNiAuvjoAzLNAG4BRAYoAixAtGWkeuK7hobaACw6VmdHsyN9LpLftJlPXxGDX8AcwA6LGAoUlwAV3JoRFxKBKIAFW4OAG8MaEzSAA8aAF5oAHIi0sqAGgKAOSSAI1JmaArK5vI25nqCszJOqqHSAcgAXyg44so6L1kOADEBaWUAYTCBcJH8mGD0olQUtIzsngLRAjbRE94iZn1wgtwCclJ7x+eoachZ+aLIg5aBbXARPYFNwedreXgnABKbGUGlEnGwzGYBE4AB5VuswREAHy-GaQEqAmjAuQIugAdxxG2gJTItl4oO24SJkIOAG0ANLBaCNd58RlEgC6JwA4qQiPjRMoLqQcQBRUpYxhEHHIdyeOHiurQXLQN4fE6CyZE3mVfRHSoSklTMmgaDqx4ELXsiwJAyObTQaH6tbsrTuZIWULgnZLBowOACSKkSLG02ik6VFgeerQSJ56CTaAAH1TZs+VU4a0VAH0iDm8ynCyBYpBqRxdTCvCHGczSvFlOzCTtuRUNjag7CQw7eYleu0JS64LKiOyiC40x92QGA2vXHrJz4w3QI0xObHdInk1Us5RKsWK1XlLW782oG3haLeD2Wf3B5yR6C477l2fDTrOfQSjaZYOouEDxtAy6ruu-CKAQHTvgGBD4KkRyFDkMRviCy4KkqOQ4sqvasgO0AANakJwO45AGOHnDkI4FBRP5sqcRzKpENREAU0DQAA-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-VUD-VYzDtwcXu8zn+eF8XWpl+46FOFX4m1-XQRNy30BtwUJOI8jcaY0AA))

```
/**
 * WIP:
 *
 * An attempt to create typescript-level type validation of
 * initialData dependent on the properties defined in config.
 */
enum InputType {
  Text = 'Text',
  Number = 'Number',
  Date = 'Date',
}

export type FieldConfig = {
  input: InputType
  label: string
  name: string
}

export type Config = {
  properties: ReadonlyArray<FieldConfig>
}

export type Row<C extends Config> = {
  [K in Names<C>]: GetFieldType<Extract<Properties<C>, { name: K }>['input']>
}

/* Extracts a union of properties from a config type,
 * i.e. { name: 'crop', ... } | { name: 'yield_t', ... } */
type Properties<C extends Config> = C['properties'][number]

/* Gets the names of of the properties from a config type,
 * i.e. 'crop' | 'yield_t' */
type Names<C extends Config> = C['properties'][number]['name']

/**
 * Gets the scalar type of an Input Type
 */
type GetFieldType<Type extends keyof typeof InputType> =
  Type extends InputType.Text
    ? string
    : Type extends InputType.Date
      ? string
      : Type extends InputType.Number
        ? number
        : never

/**
 * Converts an union of Properties into a mapped object type, i.e.:
 *
 * properties: [{ name: 'crop', ... }, { name: 'yield_t', ... }]
 * ->
 * {
 *   'crop': { name: 'crop', ... },
 *   'yield_t': { name: 'yield_t', ... },
 * }
 */
type NameMap<C extends Config> = {
  [PropertyName in Names<C>]: Extract<Properties<C>, { name: PropertyName }>
}

const render = <C extends Config>(config: C, initialData: Row<C>[]) => {
  return initialData
}

const config = {
  properties: [
    {
      input: InputType.Text,
      label: 'Crop',
      name: 'crop',
    },
    {
      input: InputType.Number,
      label: 'Yield(t)',
      name: 'yield_t',
    },
  ],
}

const initialData: Row<typeof config>[] = [
  { crop: 'corn', yield_t: 2 },
  { crop: 'barley', yield_t: 2 },
  // @ts-expect-error this should fail :(
  { crop: 2, yield_t: 'ten' },
]

render(
  config,
  // @ts-expect-error this should fail :(
  initialData,
)
```

In the end, my `Row` type has generic string keys, whose properties are a union of possible input values:

[image]

Ideally, the inferred definition would look like:

```
type MyRow = {
  crop: string;
  yield_t: number
}
```

Comment: You might want to add `as const` after the value of `config`.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wQqoJw) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz yes that's a big improvement! I'd love some explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In what follows I'm only going to deal with `FieldConfig` and not `Config`.  Instead of taking a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) parameter `C extends Config` and then [indexing into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) it like `C["properties"][number]` to get a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) of `FieldConfig`s, we'll just start with `F extends FieldConfig` as the desired union.

The approach I'd take would be to define a mapping interface

```
interface FieldTypeMap {
  [InputType.Text]: string;
  [InputType.Number]: number;
  [InputType.Date]: string
}
```

which lets you look up the field type for a given `InputType` via [indexed access](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html).  This is as opposed to your generic [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) of the form `T extends InputType.Text ? string : ⋯`.  Generic indexed accesses are much easier for TypeScript to handle than generic conditional types.

Now we can define `Row<F>` as:

```
type Row<F extends FieldConfig> =
  { [T in F as T["name"]]: FieldTypeMap[T["input"]] }
```

which uses [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) to iterate over each union member `T` of `F` and use the `name` and `input` properties to determine the key and value respectively.  This is more straightforward than trying to use [`Extract`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) to find the right union member of `F`.

Let's test out this part of it with your example:

```
const config = {
  properties: [
    {
      input: InputType.Text,
      label: 'Crop',
      name: 'crop',
    },
    {
      input: InputType.Number,
      label: 'Yield(t)',
      name: 'yield_t',
    },
  ],
} as const;

type MyRow = Row<typeof config["properties"][number]>;
/* type MyRow = {
    crop: string;
    yield_t: number;
} */
```

Note that I used a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) on the `config` definition to ask the type checker to keep track of the [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) of the string properties involved, especially that of the `name` properties.  Otherwise it would have just been seen as `string` and there'd be no hope of using them as keys.  Anyway the `MyRow` type looks good.

---

Now we can define `render()` in terms of `Row<F>`:

```
const render = <const F extends FieldConfig>(
  config: { properties: readonly F[] },
  initialData: readonly Row<F>[]
) => {
  return initialData
}
```

I also added a [`const` modifier](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-5-0.html#const-type-parameters) on the `F` type parameter to give the type checker a hint that if you enter an object literal argument for `config` that it should again keep track of the literal types of the properties.

And let's try it out:

```
render({
  properties: [
    {
      input: InputType.Text,
      label: 'Crop',
      name: 'crop',
    },
    {
      input: InputType.Number,
      label: 'Yield(t)',
      name: 'yield_t',
    },
  ],
}, [
  { crop: 'corn', yield_t: 2 }, // okay
  { crop: 'barley', yield_t: 2 }, // okay
  { crop: 2, yield_t: 'ten' }, // error!
  //~~~~     ~~~~~~~ <-- Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'
  // ^-- Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'
])
```

Looks good.  The compiler expects the second argument to be an array of `{crop: string; yield_t: number}` objects, and thus the last element is incorrect.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAkiAOYAuAVAnvYUDeBYAUFFCsAB5JQC8UA5CeTQDQFEBykARsAE5W3sQu3JiygARAIZIs1GpOkj8AXwIBLENO4AzCQGMsAMVXAANgBN0mALIT4OUQG04iVBmAA6ekgC6ALigAzkjc6gDmANyOzsiWHgJCflDggjyRhFBOCDFu7vLAiUEhIKEEKvgESG5QRqZmAMIA9iBaqqF8eOnqLv7RrpiiJhJcJv6FYaIgEhDAo8HjygQVVY3Nre2i8NwNmNxIxgH+AErAEmZNJmgAgtzcEmgAPDXmKy2hAHyli-iVmFCHDQB3R5QMjSEBmALVYzPJqvN5UUTYDIoKDqapQCSQlAOABEk2mOO8iSeFjcNngDmxOK6yEJ3igZS+BF0TSCUBZqza1A6RE22x4e2ABwyoiIPKIEppSB6WT6Hi8zHSEqgg2G-hodS28EUyqI+JmtF0Wp1EqUiuV4uVUplLli7niPHNutVpnVAE1oWYABRIACUJuV+vVaE9AH0kAGGU7vIqlBjIRygl8flgrGh-gC+Bn7imGlp2bDWri+TtBQFCQ5kgk3mkAPQAKigKagaYz6yV7K1syKEVFUBDtXD-irqVKUHrta+iYo6lUewkJnkEiOgJzbjzBc5xa1Av2FZH3G8bwc9OoDkRne26pZ3BATH7YelUAATFGL0ar7QOBJuCZgGh7wHcwhxfN90iRD94H8Z9GAfQcnxoMEaDA+lMU3II0inVkKG4UAzB4Ph7mndFQTwyESReVo3i9UQOVefwkRLXchX8XDTnONBqhPMCiFnedFykZcoDYs4QAuP5VwMY9vAIX0qHhcVcKQMBb1REA51UBcl0+cp8Fw8EeBo9I6NaJ0+M0gSkAkRVfS+fT8O4L1xSY3Z9n8c8O0tSVZRtbJME8UEnWVF0RloTVtkjPUpgNGhIMjM0+y83ifNgWU7QdbggolEL3U9H1-SyqLpmDR94ujWNYI8sVLygw0GlvQDH2gqMoFrWsoAaABrO53y7L8fz-ADYKAswQNfM1WvarqevAmroOGpraCQlq2pBG56oAQlENqAD89p23V9qOqB7gAWlO4gqhoMZimQ1RIRABoKExAJWkmDg-ybBomyug8aG29qAD1zsu34aD+1EHqe+NXtCd7PqQb7m2uuZboIbxfSAA)